# Can every member of a $\sigma$-algebra be represented by a countable union of disjoint members?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Sigma$ be a $\sigma$-algebra generated by a set of disjoint events $\mathcal{E}$ such that the sample space is $\Omega = \bigcup_{E \in \mathcal{E}} E$. Let $A \in \Sigma$. Is there always a sequence $E_1, E_2, \ldots$ of disjoint events in $\mathcal{E}$ such that $$ \bigcup_n E_n = A ?$$

Comment: I don't think a Borel set constructed at stage omega will satisfy this in general.

Comment: How about $A_1 = A$ and $A_n = \varnothing\;(n>1)$ ;-) You presumably want to assume your sets to be non-empty. Think about countable, measurable partitions...

Comment: Thank you. I changed the question accordingly ;-)

Comment: To distill Qiaochu's answer further: Take the $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that is generated by $\{0 \}$. Generating a $\sigma$-algebra requires taking complements, and $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0\}$ certainly can't be written as a union of $\{ 0 \}$. Perhaps you want to modify the question further in some way?

Comment: Thank you, I added another condition (I thought it was obvious somehow).

Comment: There might be a misconception at the heart of this question, namely the belief that the Borel sigma-algebra of $\mathbb R$ is generated by the class of the singletons. Not so, the latter being a strictly smaller sigma-algebra than the former.

Comment: Yes, I admit that this is part of the misconception. But the spirit in the answers given here in the end always boil down to say that the set $\mathcal{E}$ is uncountable, and this is why no countable union allows representing a given $B$. While this is obvious (to understand), I actually intended to ask about the case where $\mathcal{E}$ is countable... then it's not so obvious to me anymore :-(

Comment: In the answer of MichaelGreinecker. What does he mean by "these sets" in "these sets form a σ-algebra"? Can you write them down formally? I am trying to prove what he thinks is straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $\Omega$ uncountable, and the family $\mathcal E$ consists of the singletons $\{a\}$ with $a \in \Omega$.  Certainly $\Omega$ itself is in the generated $\sigma$-algebra, but is not a countable union of elements of $\mathcal E$.

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the disjoint events $\{ n \}, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Then, for example, $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}$ doesn't have this form.

Comment: Does the statement at least hold for the Borel algebra and the algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets?

Comment: @Keshav: what are the disjoint events in those cases?

Comment: @Quiaochu thanks, I didn't make my question precise enough; the union of the disjoint events should be equal to the sample space.

Answer (score 2):

Extending on the answer of GEdgar:

For every $B$ in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{E}$, there is a countable family $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\mathcal{E}$ such that $B=\bigcup\mathcal{C}$ or $B=\Omega\setminus\bigcup\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: thank you. I find this surprising and very interesting. Do you have a reference? I was actually expecting that the elements of $\mathcal{E}$ had to possibly undergo many of union and complementation operations to represent a given $B \in \sigma(\mathcal{E})$.

Comment: The proof is straightforward: You just verify that these sets form a $\sigma$-algebra. Since they must be in the $\sigma$-algebra generated, you are done then. Note that since all sets you start with, there is no operation that can further break them into smaller pieces.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker What do you mean by "these sets" in "these sets form a $\sigma$-algebra"? Can you write them down formally? I am trying to prove what you think is straightforward.

Comment: @MikeBrown The sets that are generated by some countable subfamily of generators.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Could you please tell me what is "generators" in your comment?

Comment: @MikeBrown Formally, you show that the family $\{B\in\sigma(\mathcal{E}):B\in\sigma(\mathcal{C})\text{ for some countable subfamily }\mathcal{C}\subseteq\mathcal{E}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. The elements of $\mathcal{E}$ are *generators* of $\sigma(E)$.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker. Should $\sigma(E)$ be $\sigma(\mathcal{E})$?

Comment: @MikeBrown Uhm, yes it should.