# Inverse of the Third Axiom in the Definition of a Sigma Algebra

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory

$\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra if it satisfies the following three properties:

- $X$ is in $\Sigma$, and $X$ is considered to be the universal set in
  the following context.
- $\Sigma$ is closed under complementation: If $A$ is in $\Sigma$, then
  so is its complement, $A^{c}=X-A$.
- $\Sigma$ is closed under countable unions: If $A_{1}$, $A_{2}$,
  $A_{3}$, ... are in $\Sigma$, then so is $A=A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup
     A_{3}\cup\ldots$.

If the above three are our definitions.

- Can we show that if  $A=A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup A_{3}\cup\ldots$ and $A$ is in $\Sigma$ then each of the $A_{i}$ are in $\Sigma$?
- Do we need any additional conditions to show this or would the three basic axioms suffice?

Notes:

1. I found some related discussions, but am unable to see if my doubts can be cleared using the pointers from these threads. Listing them below for completeness:

[Can every member of a $\sigma$-algebra be represented by a countable union of disjoint members?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468577/can-every-member-of-a-sigma-algebra-be-represented-by-a-countable-union-of-di?rq=1)

[Show that any element of a sigma algebra is the union of disjoint sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142962/show-that-any-element-of-a-sigma-algebra-is-the-union-of-disjoint-sets?rq=1)

1. I was trying to understand the concept in the question asked since the corresponding property seemed to be required to show that If $E$ has $\sigma$-finite measure, then $E$ is inner regular (Rudin RCA, Definition 2.16, some related threads below):

[If $E$ has $\sigma$-finite measure, then $E$ is inner regular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199938/if-e-has-sigma-finite-measure-then-e-is-inner-regular)

[Rudin Real And Complex Definition 2.16](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325009/rudin-real-and-complex-definition-2-16?noredirect=1&lq=1)

This point is clarified: If $E$ is in a sigma algebra $\Sigma$ and $E$ has $\sigma$-finite measure then it is a countable union of sets, $E_{i}$ with finite measure ($\mu\left(E_{i}\right)<\infty$). Which means the sets that make up the union of $E$ are already in $\Sigma$ since the measure $\mu$ is defined only on the members of the sigma algebra $\Sigma$. Hence the $E_{i}$ belong to the sigma algebra, $\Sigma$

1. Though my original doubt is clarified, I am still curios about the conditions under which the reverse of the third axiom hold. It is quite possible that I am missing something very basic. Happy to delete this question, if that is the case once my doubt is clarified.

Comment: You want some assumptions, or else any set $S$ would be measurable: we'd reason "$X$ is in $\Sigma$, and $X = X \cup S$, so $S$ is in $\Sigma$".

Comment: @MishaLavrov, How do we conclude that $S$ is in $\Sigma$? I am not sure. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: In your first bullet, what does it mean for a set to be in $X$?  Do you mean in $\Sigma$?  This is trivially false, consider $X = \mathbb{N}$ and $\Sigma = \{\mathbb{N}, \emptyset\}$, with $A_n = \{n\}$.

Comment: Can you explain where you think the linked proof is using this alleged property?

Comment: The question has two answers and I really do not see where either of them uses any such property.  I suspect you are misunderstanding something, but I'm not sure what it is.  Can you point out a specific sentence?

Comment: Your question: if  $A=A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup A_{3}\cup\ldots$ and $A$ is in $\Sigma$ then each of the $A_{i}$ are in $\Sigma$?

The answer is **no**.  Here is a counter-exemple: Let $A_1$ be a non-measurable subset of $[0,1]$. Let  $A_2 = [0,1] \setminus A_1$. Let $A_3=A_4=\ldots = \emptyset$. We have 
$$A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup A_{3}\cup\ldots = A_{1}\cup A_{2}=[0,1] \in \Sigma$$ 
But $A_1\notin \Sigma$ and $A_2 \notin \Sigma$.

Comment: @Ramiro, Thanks for this clarification. Could you please provide an example of $A_{1}$ or an example of a non measurable subset of [0,1]?

Comment: In my comment above, I actually considered $\Sigma$ to be the Lebesgue (or Borel) $\sigma$-algebra in  $\Bbb R$. It is a known fact that there are subsets of $[0,1]$ which are not Lebesgue measurable (and not Borel measurable). One family of such sets is called Vitali set. See, for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set .

Comment: If we consider arbitrary $\sigma$-algebras, it is even simpler to produce a counter-exemple. Let $X=\{a, b\}$  and let $\Sigma=\{\emptyset, X\}$. It is easy to see that $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Now,  let $A_1=\{a\}$, $A_2 = \{b\}$ and  $A_3=A_4=\ldots = \emptyset$. We have 
$$A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup A_{3}\cup\ldots = A_{1}\cup A_{2}=\{a, b\} = X \in \Sigma$$ 
But $A_1\notin \Sigma$ and $A_2 \notin \Sigma$.

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@texmex wrote "I am still curios about the conditions under which the reverse of the third axiom hold".

Let us prove the following result.

> Let $X$ be a set and $\Sigma$ be a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$. Then the condition
>
> - if  $A=A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup A_{3}\cup\ldots$ and $A$ is in $\Sigma$ then each of the $A_{i}$ are in $\Sigma$
>
> is true if and only  $\Sigma = 2^X$.

where $2^X$ means the collection of all subsets of $X$

**Proof**: $(\Rightarrow)$ We already have tha $\Sigma \subseteq 2^X$. So all we need to prove is that  $2^X  \subseteq \Sigma  $.

Suppose that,

- if  $A=A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup A_{3}\cup\ldots$ and $A$ is in $\Sigma$ then each of the $A_{i}$ are in $\Sigma$.

Let $E$ be any element of $2^X$, that means any subset of $X$. We can take $A_1=E$, $A_2 = X$ and  $A_3=A_4=\ldots = \emptyset$. We have
$$A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup A_{3}\cup\ldots = E\cup X = X \in \Sigma$$ so, by the condition, we have that each of the $A_{i}$ are in $\Sigma$. In particular $A_1 \in \Sigma$, which means $E \in \Sigma$. Since $E$ is an arbitrary element of $2^X$, we have that $2^X \subseteq \Sigma$. So we have $\Sigma = 2^X$.

$(\Leftarrow)$  If $\Sigma = 2^X$, then all subsets of $X$ are in $\Sigma$ and the condition

- if  $A=A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup A_{3}\cup\ldots$ and $A$ is in $\Sigma$ then each of the $A_{i}$ are in $\Sigma$

becomes trivially true.

**Remark**: Another way to prove $(\Rightarrow)$ is by the counter-positive, which consists in showing that if $\Sigma \neq 2^X$, then there is always a counter-example to

- if  $A=A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup A_{3}\cup\ldots$ and $A$ is in $\Sigma$ then each of the $A_{i}$ are in $\Sigma$

In fact, suppose $\Sigma \neq 2^X$. then there is $E \in 2^X$ such that $E \notin \Sigma$. Take $A_1=E$, $A_2 = X$ and  $A_3=A_4=\ldots = \emptyset$. We have
$$A_{1}\cup A_{2}\cup A_{3}\cup\ldots = E\cup X = X \in \Sigma$$
but $A_1=E \notin \Sigma$.

Comment: Deeply appreciative of your clarifications, examples and for this detailed answer. I will take some time to digest your answer and will accept once I am fully clear regarding it. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: @texmex , Ok. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer.

Comment: I just had one additional clarification. Your proof is absolutely complete and easy to understand given your clear exposition. I was wondering if the condition that the sigma algebra equals the power set or the collection of all subsets of the universal set ($\sigma$-algebra, $\Sigma=2^{X}$) can be relaxed. Or is there is some way to show that there is no way to relax this condition for the result asked in the question to hold. Please let me know if my doubt is not clear or if I am over complicating it somehow.

Comment: Since it is an "if and only if"  result, there is no way to relax the condition $\Sigma = 2^X$. Note also that the "proof by counter-positive" presented in the **Remark**, shows that, if the condition $\Sigma = 2^X$ is relaxed, then we can immediately (and in a standard way)  produce a counter-example to result asked in the question. So the condition $\Sigma = 2^X$ can not be relaxed.

Answer (score 1):

In the proof you're confused by, the $\sigma$-finite condition is used to construct a *specific* union with this property. This does not mean that an *arbitrary* union needs this property.

If $(X, \Sigma)$ is a measurable space, a measure $\mu$ is called $\sigma$-finite if there is some way to write $X = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ where $X_n \in \Sigma$ and $\mu(X_n) < \infty$ for all $n$.

It follows from this definition that for every $A \in \Sigma$, we can write $A = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ where $A_n \in \Sigma$ and $\mu(A_n) < \infty$ for all $n$. Just take $A_n = A \cap X_n$. (And this is what we mean by the set $A$ being $\sigma$-finite.)

Note that the definition specifically promises us some measurable sets. We don't need the much stronger and usually false property that *every* way of writing $A$ as a union $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ will result in $A_n \in \Sigma$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand this and for clearing my confusion. I am still curios of the conditions under which the reverse holds and if it is necessary somewhere. I am very new to Real and Complex Analysis (clearly as can be seen). Will wait to see if something comes up.